# Crear tabla pivot para realizar consulta

Tags: mariadb, pivot

Buen día.
Necesito consultar un total de registros, el cual los agrupo por áreas de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT AREA, COUNT(*) AS numeroTareasArea FROM sio_gestion_tareas_2 GROUP BY AREA
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que los areas pasen a ser columnas con su total de tareas, teniendo en cuenta que las áreas pueden aumentar o disminuir (datos dinamicos) una vez se vayan ingresando o quitando  tareas

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu motor de base de datos y versión?

Comment: Mariadb version 10.2.39

Comment: O tambien si se podria hacer meidiante subconsultas, pero teniendo en cuenta que las áreas pueden aumentar o disminuir